# Mail sent to gmail goes directly into spam

Tags: spam, email

First I would like to state I already searched through the database for similar questions to mine. Tried all of those suggestions but none really seem to work.

The problem is the following:
I developed a web application (cakePHP) that should send an e-mail whenever a new user registers for example. However when I try to send to a gmail address, gmail marks it as spam. I'm not using the mail() function but use smtp for the delivery.

SPF passes, DKIM passes, rDNS is setup correctly (checked by servint).

However, I've got the same problem whenever I try to send an e-mail through a web client in cpanel (roundcube in this case). Mails sent through roundcube to a gmail address also end up in spam. So I guess it's some kind of server setting, but according to servint all seems ok. I'm on a dedicated server by the way. Also checked if my ip has been blacklisted, but that's not the case also.

You guys maybe have any more suggestions? :)

Thanks

```
    Delivered-To: emailaddress@gmail.com
    Received: by 10.220.77.71 with SMTP id f7csp117778vck;
            Thu, 10 Oct 2013 01:17:52 -0700 (PDT)
    X-Received: by 10.180.100.202 with SMTP id fa10mr6509208wib.8.1381393071504;
            Thu, 10 Oct 2013 01:17:51 -0700 (PDT)
    Return-Path: <noreply@fitnesswinkel.be>
    Received: from buzzer.inboundhost.be (buzzer.inboundhost.be. [199.167.44.77])
            by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id ea7si5497937wib.43.1969.12.31.16.00.00
            (version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
            Thu, 10 Oct 2013 01:17:51 -0700 (PDT)
    Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of noreply@fitnesswinkel.be designates 199.167.44.77 as permitted sender) client-ip=199.167.44.77;
    Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
           spf=pass (google.com: domain of noreply@fitnesswinkel.be designates 199.167.44.77 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=noreply@fitnesswinkel.be;
           dkim=pass header.i=@fitnesswinkel.be
    Received: from localhost ([127.0.0.1]:40730 helo=buzzer.inboundhost.be)
        by buzzer.inboundhost.be with esmtpa (Exim 4.80.1)
        (envelope-from <noreply@fitnesswinkel.be>)
        id 1VUBRO-000447-AM
        for emailaddress@gmail.com; Thu, 10 Oct 2013 04:17:50 -0400
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8;
     format=flowed
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
    Date: Thu, 10 Oct 2013 04:17:50 -0400
    From: noreply@fitnesswinkel.be
    To: emailaddress@gmail.com
    Subject: een mail
    Message-ID: <dda53f0118b11663d941262200006e1f@fitnesswinkel.be>
    X-Sender: noreply@fitnesswinkel.be
    User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail/0.9.3
    X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
    X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - buzzer.inboundhost.be
    X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - gmail.com
    X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [47 12] / [47 12]
    X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - fitnesswinkel.be
    X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: buzzer.inboundhost.be: authenticated_id: noreply@fitnesswinkel.be
    X-Source: 
    X-Source-Args: 
    X-Source-Dir:
```

Comment: Cpanel?  Really?  You should get rid of that.  It's a horrible crutch, and quite handy for hackers.  Anyway, gmail's spam filtering is a black box that includes all kinds of things like the content of messages, historical data, your domain, and only they know what else, in addition to things like DKIM and SPF and DNSBL and RDNS validation.

Comment: Have you tried to add server's IP to DNS Whitelist (http://www.dnswl.org/)?

Comment: Just tried that, now waiting for a response. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the same at my last company, and there's no info from Gmail about it (to speak of). Luckily I'm friends with some of the best email deliverability people in the country, so these tips may help:

Firstly Gmail seems to penalise new domains. There's nothing you can do about that but keep emailing and hope it clears up eventually. Register your domain everywhere - Google Analytics, WebMaster tools, get it search indexed and showing up well in Google. Blog about it.

Secondly yes, ask your users to whitelist you. The more people do that the less likely gmail's global filter will hate you.

Make sure things are properly formatted: It seems everything is here, but we got caught by things like a weakly formatted Message-Id header.

Watch out for words like "Free". Capitalisation matters to google too, so "free" won't get caught as bad.

Add in extended formatting for To and From, i.e. full name in quotes, and address in angle brackets: "John Doe"

I hope these tips help. Gmail are very un-transparent about this stuff. The first point is the biggest problem, and impossible to get around.

Comment: Didn't manage to solve the problem, but will accept this answer as it's the most contributive.

Comment: Thanks. I honestly feel your pain. Gmail's filtering is (in my slightly biased opinion) terrible.

Answer (score 0):

We are going through exactly the same thing at the moment.

One thing we are currently trying out is to send from a real email account and not a noreply. We got rejections from Hotmail due to:

```
SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
host mx1.hotmail.com [65.54.188.126]: 550 5.7.0 (BAY0-MC4-F31) Message could not be delivered. Please ensure the message is RFC 5322 compliant.
```

RFC 2822 and RFC 5322 both say that "In all cases, the "From:" field SHOULD NOT contain any mailbox that does not belong to the author(s) of the message."

Not sure if that will make a difference to Gmail as, like any email provider, they change the rules frequently to stay ahead of the spammers but it did work for us with Hotmail.

The other thing which DOES work is to ask your recipients to add you to their whitelist - it is painful for signups, of course, but it is the first thing we ask new members to do.

Comment: Still the same when sending from a real email account, unfortunately.